# Android test with Espresso IdlingResource

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to test that the `AutoCompleteTextView` will show the items after some word will be typed. But there is a delay between typing and showing the popup. First i was using `Thread.sleep()` and it was working just fine. But I know that this approach isn't clear so I'm trying to accomplish it with `IdlingResource`. But it doesn't work for me. I literally read first 5 pages of Google responses, but either I don't understand how it should work, or I have some error in my code.

Here is the code:

```
static class AutocompleteShowIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private Activity activity;
    private @IdRes int resId;
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    public AutocompleteShowIdlingResource(Activity activity, @IdRes int resId) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + resId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        boolean idle = ((AutoCompleteTextView) activity.findViewById(resId)).getAdapter() != null;
        Log.d(TAG, "isIdleNow: " + idle);
        if (idle) {
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }
        return idle;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
        this.resourceCallback = callback;

    }
}
```

The test itself:

```
    Activity activity = calibrationActivityRule.getActivity();
    onView(withId(R.id.autocomplete_occupation)).perform(typeText("dok"));
    IdlingResource idlingResource = new AutocompleteShowIdlingResource(activity, R.id.autocomplete_occupation);
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);
    assertEquals(((AutoCompleteTextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_occupation)).getAdapter().getCount(), 3);
    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
```

But the test fails on `java.lang.NullPointerException` when trying to call `getCount()` on null adapter. The log is printing

```
isIdleNow: false
```

just once, which is quite strange.

There isn't much clear examples how to use IdlingResource, so maybe someone can make it clear for me. Thanks.

Comment: Please, show how did you get 'activity'.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IdlingResource will have an effect only if you use it together with onView(...).check(...) or onData(...).check(...). Actually, the "magic" will happen in the check call - it's the place where Espresso waits until there are no running AsyncTasks or no blocking IdlingResources.

Now let's correct your code so that it works:

```
Activity activity = calibrationActivityRule.getActivity();
onView(withId(R.id.autocomplete_occupation)).perform(typeText("dok"));
IdlingResource idlingResource = new AutocompleteShowIdlingResource(activity, R.id.autocomplete_occupation);

try {
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);

    //that's where Espresso will wait until the idling resource is idle
    onData(anything()).inAdapter(withId(R.id.autocomplete_occupation)).check(matches(isDisplayed()); 
finally {
    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
}
assertEquals(((AutoCompleteTextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_occupation)).getAdapter().getCount(), 3);
```